# What are the steps behind "Should Be True ${hex_value}==${0xFF}" expression in Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

Consider the following code in built-in-library-tests.robot:

```
***Test Cases***
Use "Convert To Hex"

     ${hex_value} =         Convert To Hex  255   base=10  prefix=0x        # Result is 0xFF

     # Question: How does the following statement work step by step?
     Should Be True      ${hex_value}==${0xFF}           #: is ${0xFF} considered by Robot a string or a integer value in base 16?

     # To Answer My Own Question, here is an hypothesis solution:
     # For python to execute the expression:
     # Should Be True      a_python_expression_in_a_string_without_quotes      # i.e.   0xFF==255

     # To reach that target, i think of a 2 step solution:  
     # STEP 1: When a variable is used in the expressing using the normal ${hex_value} syntax, its value is replaced before the expression is evaluated.
     # This means that the value used in the expression will be the string representation of the variable value, not the variable value itself.
     Should Be True      0xFF==${0xFF}

     # Step 2: When the hexadecimal value 0xFF is given in ${} decoration, robot converts the value to its
     # integer representation 255 and puts the string representation of 255 into the the expression
     Should Be True      0xFF==255
```

The test above passes with all its steps. I want to check with my community, is my 2 step hypothesis solution correct or not? Does Robot exactly go through these steps, before evaluating the final expression `0xFF==255` in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robot receives the expression as the string `${hex_value}==${0xFF}`. It then performs variable substitution, yielding the string `0xFF==255`. This string is then passed to python's [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) statement.

The reason for the right hand side being `255` is described in [the user guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#number-variables):

> It is possible to create integers also from binary, octal, and hexadecimal values using 0b, 0o and 0x prefixes, respectively. The syntax is case insensitive.

`${0xFF}` gets replaced with 255, and `${hex_value}` gets substituted with whatever is in that variable. In this case, that variable contains the four bytes `0xFF`.

Thus, `${hex_value}==${0xFF}` gets converted to `0xFF==255`, and that gets passed to `eval` as a string.

In other words, it's exactly the same as if you had typed `eval("0xFF==255")` at a python interactive prompt.